# How do I get correct indentation for HTML and Javascript in gVim?

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc

I've been using vim and gVim for over a year. I use it mainly for editing of HTML, PHP, Python and Javascript.

Every time I've tried to set some automatic type of indentation I've got into troubles. Now I just use `autoindent`. I use it both at home in Windows 7 and at work in Linux.

Things I'm missing is:

- Right indentation after ending a line
- correct indentation when I use `=`.

I've tried to install many of the gvim plugins and I still get no practical results. I set `syntax` and `smartindent` or `cindent`, also `filetypeplugin` (I can post my `.vimrc` if needed).

The PHP is less of a worry to me, my main issue is indenting HTML and Javascript (e.g. jQuery).

Comment: I don't know what "right indentation after ending a line" or "correct indentation when I use =" means. It would help to see examples of what you do, what you expect, and what you see instead.

Comment: What settings are you using to enable indentation for PHP/HTML/JavaScript files?  ":filetype indent on" in your ~/.vimrc is probably the optimal method, and it works fine for me.

Comment: my `indentKeys` was set to empty string. I've removed lines where it was set that way.

Answer (score 1):

Without any particular plugin and these settings in my .vimrc

```
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=0
set noexpandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set shiftround
set autoindent
set copyindent
```

I get what I think is "correct indentation when I use =" (`|` is the cursor).

```
var myObj = {
foo : "bar"|
};
```

becomes this when I type `=`:

```
var myObj = {
  foo : "bar"|
};
```

With the same example, I get correct indentation when hitting `<CR>`.

```
var myObj = {
  foo : "bar"|
};
```

becomes this:

```
var myObj = {
  foo : "bar"
  |
};
```

I think `set copyindent` is what you need.